# Vectors Calculation Question

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-analysis, classical-mechanics

When two vectors are sketched from a single point, the angle between them is θ.  Show that the size of their vector summation is given in the expression: $ \sqrt{A^2 + B^2 +2ABcosθ} $.

Any suggestions on how one might tackle this one?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $\|A+B\|^2=\|A\|^2+2\langle A,B\rangle+\|B\|^2$ and $\langle A,B\rangle\cdot \|A\|\cdot\|B\|=\cos(\theta)$.